# How to specify two value as DEFAULT on a column by shuffling between two values on any insertion

Tags: sql, random, mariadb

I have a table called user_profile with these three columns. What i am trying to do is when i don't specify any value for cover_pic column then it must insert the default random value from the given two values.

Like example sometime it insert ABC.png as default value and sometime XYZ.png.

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile(
    profileId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    profile_pic VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT "profile.png",
    cover_pic VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT RAND("ABC.png","xyz.png"),
    CONSTRAINT pk_profileId PRIMARY KEY(profileId)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the `DEFAULT` on the table directly. But you can use a [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to set a random picture filename to the column `cover_pic` if `NULL`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_cover_pic BEFORE INSERT ON user_profile
  FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW.cover_pic = IF(NEW.cover_pic IS NULL, ELT(FLOOR(RAND()*2)+1, 'pic1', 'pic2'), NEW.cover_pic);
```

Using this `TRIGGER` you can use a `INSERT INTO` without specify the column `cover_pic` (or using `NULL` on column `cover_pic`):

```
INSERT INTO user_profile (profile_pic) VALUES ('test.png');
INSERT INTO user_profile (profile_pic, cover_pic) VALUES ('test.png', NULL);
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1fb1e33ad7a00baefa281d561cea829)